# Facebook post feed api thumbnail missing

Tags: php, facebook

I had two different domains which are using the same Facebook API to post feed on my wall. The code is as below:

```
function postToFeed() 
{
// calling the API ...
var obj = {
  method: 'feed',
  link: '<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].Yii::app()->baseUrl."/index.php?r=campaign/view&id=$model->campaign_id";?>',
  picture: '<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].Yii::app()->baseUrl."/$model->campaign_image";?>',
  name: '<?php echo $model->campaign_title;?>',
  caption: 'Demo',
  description: '<?php echo $model->campaign_description;?>'
};

function callback(response) 
{
    if (response && response.post_id) 
    {
        fbs_click(<?php echo $myid;?>,<?php echo $model->campaign_id;?>);
    } 
    else 
    {
        alert('Post was not published.');
    }
}

FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

}

On both domain, the post feed worked. But in one of the domain the thumbnail won't display. I want to know is it due to some file permission issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check your network panel and see if you're getting any errors for that file.

Comment: And check your URLs using the debug tools: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you can access the image from outside, If the image is local then it will not be fetched by Facebook,

Comment: Put the image on a different domain and try, Sometimes facebook gives  this kinda issues